# Prestigio MultiPhone 5430 and nonexistant boot/recovery partitions

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, partitions

I've got the Prestigio MultiPhone 5430. It's built on Intel Medfield platform. The phone isn't popular as it was released about 6-7 months ago.

Because (as far as I know) nobody before me has tried to hack into it, I'm seriously interested in getting this model's recovery and bootloader partition to have any modding start-point. I've already searched for any clues in `init.xxxx.rc`, `xxxx.fstab` and in `/proc` partition, however that research yielded nothing.

**What I already know is:**

- The DROIDBOOT is locked and doesn't accept any fastboot commands besides some basic info commands like `version` and one `oem erase`. I'm trying to guess possible commands.
- I'm not sure about the partition layout, devices are identified like `mmcblkX` and `mmcblkXpY` where X is device number and Y is partition number.
- The recovery seems like it's a really limited CWM recovery; allows only to install updates from ZIP and reboot, but does not allow backing up whole filesystem.
- Another way to flash bootloader is to use Intel SoC Manufacturing Tool and Medfield board drivers I got from Intel support (they actually responded and even provided some useful usage info), but then, I would have to get a bulk-upgrade file, like .KDZ for LG.

**The partition layout in FSTAB file is:**

```
/reserved hidden /dev/block/mmcblk0_none none size_hint=164
/panic    raw    /dev/block/mmcblk0p1    none size_hint=8
/factory  ext4   /dev/block/mmcblk0p2    none size_hint=32
/config   ext4   /dev/block/mmcblk0p3    none size_hint=16  ro
[then nothing helpful: media - mmcblk0p5, cache - mmcblk0p6]
/logs     ext4   /dev/block/mmcblk0p7    none size_hint=16  ro
[and then nothing really interesting, down to mmcblk0p9, then sdcard begins]
```

It's interesting that `mmcblk0_none` doesn't exist in `/dev/block`, at least at runtime. Another interesting fact is that some parts of `init.rc` were copied straight from Acer Liquid C1, as far as I can deduce from comment left-overs.

Is it possible the system is hiding some partitions from me? If so, how can I reveal them? Can I get service documentation for this Prestigio model anywhere? Has anyone done any research on this before?

I'd really appreciate pointing me into the correct direction, because I'm in dead-end of this research for about a week already.

Oh, and I already tried asking Prestigio support. They didn't answer (such a surprise!).

Answer (score 0):

While I am not nearly as well up as you, I haven't seen any replies and this might be of interest - if not to you then to others looking for info on Prestigios.

I have a Prestigio PAP 4500 Duo which bricked itself spontaneously on New Year's Eve, sleeping the sleep of death. It's under guarantee so all I was looking for was a possible reboot mechanism. I happened upon this menu which seems to offer lots more than you described. Now I couldn't navigate the menu, but that may be because of a fault, but the menu is there to be accessed.

Thanks for your info and hope this adds a little,

MJF

[image: Sleeping Peacefully :)]

<sup>(Click in the image for larger picture)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well, my recovery offers only installing .zip packages from SD card. The strange thing is, my PAP5430 has bricked itself 3 days ago after unexpected system reboot.